# Updating z3 Variable or Linear Solving

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm new to Z3, so this is likely a silly question. I'm trying to model an execution flow of a program. Doing this through manual z3 calls for now. That said, I end up trying to model something like the following:

```
x = 1
x += 1
```

Performing the following commands gives me unsat, and I understand why.

```
x = z3.Int('x')
s.add(x == 1)
s.add(x == x + 1)
```

In small scale, it might be reasonable to manually change x == 1 to x == 2. My question is, is there a way to do this in z3 where I don't have to go back and attempt to modify the variables I put into the solver? The equations obviously would get much harrier than just +1, and attempting to work through that logic manually seems error prone and sloppy.

EDIT: After adjusting my program to use SSA as suggested, it works very easily now. I did opt to keep multiple versions of the variable, but that didn't turn into too much extra work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename variables such that they are in SSA form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form).
Also, you probably don't need to introduce names for intermediate expressions. The only Z3 variables should be program inputs or things like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I get how this would work, however help me understand how the following example would behave.

Sorry - Typing happened before braining I think. Is this what you mean by SSA for z3?

    x1 = 1
    x2 = x1 + 1
    y1 = x2 + 1

In which case I would be keeping track of what version of the variable I'm talking about?

Comment: yes.  But as I said, probably you don't need to introduce new names.  Just keep track of the expression referring to each program variable.